# What is the `-l` option for `top`?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a script running. Let's say the process pid is 9000. I followed an instruction from a blog post:

```
top -l1 -pid 9000 -stats pid,th
```

and I should see as output:

```
PID    #TH
9000   102
```

On Ubuntu OS, I instead get:

```
top: unknown option 'l'
Usage:
  top -hv | -bcHiOSs -d secs -n max -u|U user -p pid(s) -o field -w [cols]
```

What is `l1`?  It is not in [the man page](http://www.unixtop.org/man.shtml).

Answer (score 3):

The `l#` flag is, at least, available on OS X, and let's you display logging samples.

From the [developer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/top.1.html):

> **-l** <samples>
>
> Use logging mode and display <samples> samples, even if standard output is a terminal.   0  is
>                 treated  as  infinity.   Rather than redisplaying, output is periodically printed in raw form.
>                 Note that the first sample displayed will have an invalid %CPU displayed for each process,  as
>                 it is calculated using the delta between samples.

The output of the command does not match the one posted, however, which could be because it has been changed in updates since the blog post was written, or the author is refering to another implementation of `top`.